# How may i retrieve Mysql data to this JSON format?

Tags: php, json

I have read about [json_encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode) but still lack the logic in using it for my needs on this particular [JSON](https://www.php.net/json) structure.

Assuming the [JSON](https://www.php.net/json) structure is as follows :

```
{
  "_id": "23441324",
  "api_rev": "1.0",
  "type": "router",
  "hostname": "something",
  "lat": -31.805412,
  "lon": -64.424677,
  "aliases": [
    {
      "type": "olsr",
      "alias": "104.201.0.29"

    }
  ],
  
  "site": "roof town hall",
  "community": "Freifunk/Berlin",
  "attributes": {
    "firmware": {
      "name": "meshkit",
      "url": "http:k.net/"
    }
  }
}
```

Some of the values of the attributes will be taken from the database while some are going to be hardcoded(static) like `"type"`,`"api_rev"`. I was thinking of just using concatenation to build the structure but learnt its a bad idea. So if i am to use [json_encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode) how may i be able to handle this structure ? array dimensions etc.

Comment: you don't retrieve in json format. You retrieve what the DB gives you, build a PHP data structure that looks like what you want, then json_encode() that structure. That means you need to learn how to deal with multi-dimensional/nested PHP arrays and objects.

Comment: @MarcB please could you give me a pseudo code of the data structure in PHP to get me started ? I hope to learn with a starter.