# Using Json_encode, Change the array name from Mysql

Tags: php, json

How can i change the array name gotten from the database : for example

If i print this `json_encode($rows)`

I have :

```
{"access":"MTAPI"}
```

But, in the Json format, i want **"access"** to be called **"Type"**.

How may i achieve this ?

Secondly, how may i push more data into the array to appear as such :

```
{"access":"MTAPI", "alias":"result"}
```

I tried but it's messy:

```
array_push($rows, "alias", "result");
```

Thirdly, if i have a whole structure will multiple sql statements that i need to perform to built it, should i use a giant array, fit everything in then pass to json_encode ? or does json_encode do some kind of concatenation ?

The array of `$row`

```
 $sth =  $dbh->query("SELECT access FROM NodeAttributes WHERE Node_ID = '$nodeid[$i]'")or die(mysql_error());
            $rows = array();
            while($r = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $rows[] = $r;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$arr_temp['Type'] = $rows['access'];
$arr_temp['alias'] = "result";

echo json_encode($arr_temp);
```

you need to create a temp array and push the `values` and `index` you want then encode it as `json`

**UPDATE 2:**

you can use this in your query like this-->

```
 $sth =  $dbh->query("SELECT access FROM NodeAttributes WHERE Node_ID = '$nodeid[$i]'")or die(mysql_error());
$rows = array();
while($r = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
       $rows['Type'] = $r['access'];
       $rows['alias'] = "result";
       echo json_encode($rows);
 }
```

Comment: This is my output : `{"Type":null,"alias":"result"}`. Is the problem from my code ?

Answer (score 2):

> But, in the Json format, i want "access" to be called "Type".
>
> How may i achieve this?

Unset the `"access"` key and set `"Type"` in its place:

```
$rows['Type'] = $rows['access'];
unset($rows['access']);
echo json_encode($rows);
```

> Secondly, how may i push more data into the array to appear as such

Just add extra key/value pairs:

```
$rows['alias'] = 'result';
```

`array_push` is a function that only very rarely has a legitimate use case, don't prefer it.

> Thirdly, if i have a whole structure will multiple sql statements that
>   i need to perform to built it, should i use a giant array, fit
>   everything in then pass to json_encode ? or does json_encode do some
>   kind of concatenation ?

It's not clear what you mean. "Giant array" vaguely sounds like the simplest practical solution, but without clarification that doesn't say much.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I tried the renaming and this is what i get instead : `{"0":{"access":"SNMP"},"Type":null}`  Then when i tried adding the extra key/value pairs, i have this output:
 `{"0":{"access":"SNMP"},"alias":"result"}` Is the output interpreted the sae as with the sample i provided above ? 
And about the last paragraph, I intend to build a structure that looks like this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21663535/how-may-i-retrieve-mysql-data-to-this-json-format?noredirect=1#comment32744469_21663535) So i was asking if it's gonna be 1 big array with sub arrays in.

Comment: @beginningperl: It seems like you meant to write `$row` instead of `$rows` in the original question; the output you give is not the whole output of `json_encode`, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can able to store result to your own variable then encode this as json.

```
$output = array( 'Type' => $row[0]['access'] );

json_encode($output);
```

Comment: This perfectly replaces Type with "access" but the value for access is now null.

Comment: may I know the values of $rows. Please give the value of $rows here. php code : `print_r($rows);` . Based upon this I can able to provide you the solution

Comment: `
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [access] => SNMP
        )

)
`
It's something of that sort.

Comment: Try `$output = array( 'Type' => $rows[0]['access'] );`